# how can I send logs to nginx reverse proxy nginx over logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

My question is simple but I could not find a solution here. I have a logstash and Elasticsearch server .Generally I can send logs to elasticsearch by logstash.

Look please below code:logstash.conf file to ship logs to elastic

```html
input {
  file {
    type => "json"
    path => ["C:/logs/*.json"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => "json"                 
  }
}
filter {
mutate {
    remove_field => [ "path" ]

}
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
 
 
 
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
       
    }
}
```

But I put a nginx between logstash and elasticsearch, I configured that but it is not working. Below error returns.

```html
input {
  file {
    type => "json"
    path => ["C:/logs/*.json"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => "json"                 
  }
}
filter {
mutate {
    remove_field => [ "path" ]

}
 ruby {
        code => "
            require 'base64';
            event['password'] = bG9ndXNlcjpidXJnYW5iYW5rXzIwMTc=
        "
    }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    http {
        http_method => "post"
        url => "http://localhost:8080;"
        format => "message"
        headers => {"Authorization" => "Basic %{password}"}
        content_type => "application/json"
        message => '{"whatever": 1 }'
    }
 
}
```

Error: [2017-09-18T11:07:30,235][ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ] [HTTP Output Failure] Encountered non-2xx HTTP code 401 {:response_code=>401, :url=>"http://localhost:8080;", :event=>2017-09-18T07:05:42.797Z test_y HTTP "EJT\ANYCUSTOMER" "" "GET" "/api/v1.0/xxxxxxx/xxxx" responded 200 in 0.0000 ms, :will_retry=>false}

Second simple solution also below but it is not working also:

```html
input {
  file {
    type => "json"
    path => ["C:/logs/*.json"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => "json"                 
  }
}
filter {
mutate {
    remove_field => [ "path" ]

}
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
   
    http {
        http_method => "post"
        url => "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
        headers => ["Authorization", "Basic dXNlcjE6JGFwcjEkNGdTY3dwMkckSlBLOXNVRmJGbzZ4UjhnSUVqYXo2Lg=="]
    }
}
```

ERROR : [ERROR][logstash.outputs.http    ] [HTTP Output Failure] Encountered non-2xx HTTP code 401 {:response_code=>401, :url=>"http://127.0.0.1:8080",

Comment: Try this `headers => ["Authorization", "Basic %{password}"]`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks. But result is the same.

Comment: So I checked by setting up a normal server and see what headers logstash sends with the POST request and it is sending the headers in both formats. Be it the array style I mentioned or be it the hash style you had used earlier. So the headers are going fine from logstash end. This may be a problem with the nginx config or the URL that you have used. You should try manually posting a file using curl to that endpoint and debug. I don't think problem is logstash here